# compile error during ubuntu kernel 5.4.0-42.46 build

Tags: 20.04, kernel, compiling

I downloaded ubuntu source by `git clone git://kernel.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-focal.git`. and because I wanted to use a specific version, I did git checkout Ubuntu-5.4.0-42.46 (this version is the one used in a ubuntu installation .iso.  See related question here : [what ubuntu source version should I use to add some debug prints? (for ubuntu boot-up debug)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1347390/what-ubuntu-source-version-should-i-use-to-add-some-debug-prints-for-ubuntu-bo) )

After git-checkout, the `git log` shows this result :

```
commit 98c4545e2d65ed35c31056f72c4da20f6b5ea0d0 (HEAD, tag: Ubuntu-5.4.0-42.46)
Author: Khalid Elmously <khalid.elmously@canonical.com>
Date:   Thu Jul 9 19:50:26 2020 -0400

    UBUNTU: Ubuntu-5.4.0-42.46
    
    Signed-off-by: Khalid Elmously <khalid.elmously@canonical.com>
```

To build the kernel, I did `ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-none-elf- make defconfig` and `ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-none-elf- make -j24 Image`.  But this gives me a compile error below.  What can be wrong?

```
  . 
  . 
  CC      mm/interval_tree.o
  CC      drivers/base/regmap/regcache.o
  CC      kernel/time/posix-cpu-timers.o
  CC      mm/list_lru.o
  CC      block/blk-mq.o
  AS      arch/arm64/lib/memchr.o
  CC      fs/ext4/migrate.o
security/security.c: In function 'security_add_hooks':
security/security.c:477:25: error: 'struct security_hook_heads' has no member named 'socket_getpeersec_stream'
  477 |     &security_hook_heads.socket_getpeersec_stream)
      |                         ^
  CC      kernel/time/posix-clock.o
  AS      arch/arm64/lib/memcmp.o
security/security.c: In function 'security_setprocattr':
  CC      arch/arm64/kvm/../../../virt/kvm/arm/vgic/vgic-v2.o
security/security.c:2058:27: error: 'union security_list_options' has no member named 'socket_getpeersec_stream'
 2058 |   socket_getpeersec_stream.socket_getpeersec_stream = NULL;
      |                           ^
In file included from ./include/linux/timer.h:5,
                 from ./include/linux/workqueue.h:9,
                 from ./include/linux/bpf.h:9,
                 from security/security.c:13:
security/security.c:2060:25: error: 'struct security_hook_heads' has no member named 'socket_getpeersec_stream'
 2060 |     &security_hook_heads.socket_getpeersec_stream,
      |                         ^
./include/linux/list.h:857:12: note: in definition of macro 'hlist_entry_safe'
  857 |  ({ typeof(ptr) ____ptr = (ptr); \
      |            ^~~
security/security.c:2059:3: note: in expansion of macro 'hlist_for_each_entry'
 2059 |   hlist_for_each_entry(hp,
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
security/security.c:2060:25: error: 'struct security_hook_heads' has no member named 'socket_getpeersec_stream'
 2060 |     &security_hook_heads.socket_getpeersec_stream,
      |                         ^
./include/linux/list.h:857:28: note: in definition of macro 'hlist_entry_safe'
  857 |  ({ typeof(ptr) ____ptr = (ptr); \
      |                            ^~~
security/security.c:2059:3: note: in expansion of macro 'hlist_for_each_entry'
 2059 |   hlist_for_each_entry(hp,
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ./include/linux/list.h:9,
                 from ./include/linux/timer.h:5,
                 from ./include/linux/workqueue.h:9,
                 from ./include/linux/bpf.h:9,
                 from security/security.c:13:
./include/linux/kernel.h:993:17: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
  993 |  void *__mptr = (void *)(ptr);     \
      |                 ^
./include/linux/list.h:847:40: note: in expansion of macro 'container_of'
  847 | #define hlist_entry(ptr, type, member) container_of(ptr,type,member)
      |                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~
  . 
  .
```

When I do the same with linux-5.4.21 source, it compiles ok.

Answer (score 0):

I found ubuntu has its own way of building the whole ubuntu including the kernel.  It's shown in here : https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel

The correct method for arm64 case was (from the above page)

```
LANG=C fakeroot debian/rules ARCH=arm64 clean
# quicker build:
LANG=C fakeroot debian/rules ARCH=arm64 binary-headers binary-generic binary-perarch
# if you need linux-tools or lowlatency kernel, run instead:
LANG=C fakeroot debian/rules ARCH=arm64 binary
```

You can add debug information using this commands (from the above page) :

```
sudo apt-get install pkg-config-dbgsym
LANG=C fakeroot debian/rules clean
LANG=C fakeroot debian/rules binary-headers binary-generic binary-perarch skipdbg=false
```